# How can I suspend my Windows 8 Pro app earlier than normal after being minimised?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am building a Windows 8 Pro application and I would like the application to enter "Suspend" state immediately after losing focus (or being 'minimized')

This is for a kiosk application (won't actually be on the Store) where I want to relaunch/refocus the application when a user tries to hide it. So far, I can only 'refocus' it using a native C# app once the app has been killed (i.e. when the process does not exist in Process.GetProcessByName()). This is why I would like to kill the application-- the user should not be minimizing it so killing it is a cost the application can bear.

How can I get the application to terminate when it is minimized? I am wondering if it is possible to set the time-out period, or to intercept a general event in App.xaml.cs when the application itself has lost focus (then perhaps call App.Exit() terminate the process). I have tried the Application.Suspending event but takes too long to fire off. It takes about 10 seconds to fire off AFTER the application has been killed with ALT+F4.

Comment: The term "minimized" is a very odd one, there's no such thing in Store apps.  At most you can lose the focus, you know about it when Application.Suspending event fires.  If you want to terminate your app from that event then that's fine, albeit that your user will be clueless why it is gonzo.  WACK will probably be unhappy about it.

Comment: That's unfortunate. The event for 'lost focus' (Suspending) does not occur straight after the application loses focus. It takes approximately 10 seconds. This is for a kiosk application (won't actually be on the Store) where I want to relaunch the application when a user tries to escape it.

Comment: You'd better focus on how you are going to run this app if you don't deploy it through the store.  You need an activation key, buying one costs thousands.  WinRT is in general highly unsuitable for a kiosk app.

Comment: Thank you for the concern. This is for an application where Windows 8 Pro is required, so desktop code is allowed. I have a desktop application to help manage to life-cycle, but it relies on the app being terminated (after Suspending). I have updated the question to reflect that :)

Comment: looks pretty similar to this one from a few days ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777131/windows-8-metro-immersive-app-force-terminate/14779519#14779519 - not sure if that will help (if not deploying through store then u may have chance); however, deploying with developer licenses isn't compliant, so unless it's Enterprise, you would need side loading keys.